# angularjs doesn't trigger validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with validation, when submiting it doesn't trigger validation message.

html looks like:

```
<div class="inputContainer" ng-class="{'error' : thisForm.keywords.$invalid && !thisForm.keywords.$pristine}">
    <div class="infoLabel">Keywords:</div>
    <input type="text" ui-select2="keywordsSelect2Options" ng-model="thesis.keywords" name="tags" required data-placeholder="Enter keywords">

    <div class="editIcon"><i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></div>
    <div class="errorIcon">
        <div class="icon"> <span>!</span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="validationMessage"><span animated-show="thisForm.keywords.$invalid && !thisForm.keywords.$pristine">You need to enter a keyword</span></div>
</div>
```

javascript file:

```
$scope.thesis = {
    keywords: [],
};
```

Am I missing something, cant find an error?

Comment: Change `thisForm.keywords.$invalid && !thisForm.keywords.$pristine` in both places to `thisForm.keywords.$invalid && (thisForm.$submitted || !thisForm.keywords.$pristine)`

Comment: that didn't help